# Which ARM Cortex M chips allow for execution from RAM?

Tags: arm

I've been playing around with writing operating system-like software, mostly as a self learning experience.  I've been doing this on the Atmel AVR processor, since it's simple enough for me to understand and get a program going quickly.  I now want to move into an architecture in which the user stores programs that are run in RAM.  I know that *some* Cortex-M chips can run from RAM, but I've heard that this is not universal.  I've checked out the datasheets for a number of them from a few different manufacturers, but I can't find any reference to execution from RAM.  For what it's worth, I have one of these: http://www.nxp.com/assets/documents/data/en/data-sheets/KL27P64M48SF2.pdf  I also have an Atmel SAMD-10, but I hate the ASF like rats so I'd rather avoid using it.

Can the chips I have execute from RAM?  Is there anything I should be looking for in a datasheet that indicates whether or not this is possible?

Comment: On STM32, Flash/RAM configuration is set up externally with the BOOT0 and BOOT1 pins.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I know that some Cortex-M chips can run from RAM, but I've heard that this is not universal.

You heard wrong. All Cortex-M chips can execute code from RAM addresses and from off-chip external ram should they support an external memory controller.

Only the interrupt vector table has a few more restrictions, which require you to put that table into on-chip ram or flash - see VTOR register description.

Note: Memory maps which describe where code is executable can be found in the coresponding [ARM Architexture Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0419c/index.html).